# let $S$ be the set $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

let $S$ be the set $(\alpha, \beta) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that

$$\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \to 0$$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

then $S$ is contain in

1. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha>0, \beta>0\}$
2. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha>2, \beta>2\}$
3. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha + \beta >1\}$
4. $\{(\alpha, \beta): \alpha + 4\beta>1\}$

this is the orginal question[image]

i think  option 1 and option 2  is only correct  answer  because by using the L hospital rule....pliz  help me  and give  me the solution as my exam  is  Tommorrow,,im very confused and depessed.....

Comment: @Jose carlos  santos   Help  me.....

Comment: There should be some absolute value in the numerator otherwise the function may not  be defined for negative x or y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 4. cannot be true, since it is not symmetric with respect to $\alpha$ and $\beta$, but the hypotesis are symmetric.

Now, suppose that $\alpha=\beta=2$. Then$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leqslant\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}2\right)^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$Therefore, the second option doesn't hold.

And if you put $\alpha=\beta=\frac14$ and $x=y$, you have$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt[4]x\sqrt[4]x}{\sqrt{2x^2}}0=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sqrt x}{2|x|},$$which is not $0$. So, option 1. doesn't hold either.

Therefore, assuming that one of the options holds, it must be the third one.

Comment: thanks a lots  @Jose Carlos santos

Comment: Sir, $\alpha+\beta>1 \implies$ limit goes to zero. what is the problem with second option? $\alpha>2$ and $\beta>0 \implies \alpha+\beta>4>1. Right?$

Comment: @Unknownx If $\alpha=\beta=2$, then the limit is $0$. So, it is *not* true that the set $S$ is a subset of $\{(\alpha,\beta):\alpha>2,\beta>2\}$.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways without putting value for $\alpha,\beta $ can be substituting $x=r\cos (t),y=r\sin (t) $ thus original limit turns into $\lim_{r\to 0} r^{\alpha+\beta -1}(\cos (t))^{\alpha}(\sin(t))^{\beta} $ which tends to $0$ if $r\to 0$ thus $\alpha+\beta-1>0$ . Which is the third option.

Comment: thanks @Archis welankar

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ and suppse that $f(x,y) \to 0$ as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Then we have with $x=y>0$:

$f(x,x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}x^{\alpha+ \beta-1} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. This gives

$\alpha+ \beta -1>0$.

Comment: @Freds   thanks a lot..